# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' (CS0029)

Tags: c#

I'm on my way to learn C# by following the basic training tutorial from Lynda and trying to make some changes on their examples.

I'm stuck on an error that I can't find a solution for on Google.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' (CS0029)

Code:

```
namespace l2
{
    class Program
    {   
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int arg;
            arg = Console.ReadLine();
            int result1;

            result1 = formula(arg);
            Console.WriteLine("the result is {0}",result1);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static int formula (int theVal){
            return (theVal * 2 + 15);
        }
        }
    }
```

I really don't understand why I get that error. My function is getting an int, the arg that I want to get from console is also an int. Where is the string that the compiler is talking about? :)

Comment: If you would just **consult the [official MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on `Console.ReadLine`**, you would see it returns **a string** (not an `int`) ....

Comment: @marc_s, that's right. Sorry, won't happen again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Console.ReadLine()` returns a string.

What you want is

```
arg = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: To expand on this... it doesn't matter what is in the console, it will always be read as a string. You have to convert it from there.

Comment: You're right, but why? The arg from `arg = Console.ReadLine();` is a string by default?

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution in this case will be.

```
string input;
                input= Console.ReadLine();
                int numberArg;
                while (!int.TryParse(input, out numberArg))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(@"Wrong parameter. Type again.");
                    input= Console.ReadLine();
                }

                var result1 = formula(numberArg);
                Console.WriteLine("the result is {0}", result1);
                Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also attempt some subtle validation, by using the `int.TryParse`.  Which will attempt to convert the value to an integer, if it indeed fails it will use the original value:

```
int id = 1;
int.TryParse("Hello", out id);
Console.WriteLine(id)
```

*Output: `1`*

```
int id = 1;
int.TryParse("40", out id);
Console.WriteLine(id)
```

*Output: `40`*

Also note that `Console.ReadLine()` will return a type of `string`. So to correctly solve your issue, you would do:

```
int arguement = 0;
while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out arguement)
{
     Console.WriteLine(@"Error, invalid integer.");
     Console.ReadLine();
}
```

So until they enter a valid integer they'll be trapped in the loop.